# How to join two curved segments with straight lines in affinity designer?

Tags: vector, affinity-designer, ipad

How do I  join two curves with straight lines in affinity designer?

Here is a screenshot of the curves separated:[image: separated curve segments]

This is what I end up with when I join nodes and close the path. I would like to connect with straight lines only.

[image: badly joined curve segments]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't use Affinity Designer, but you could adjust the Bézier curve handles, since these generally work the same in all vector software.

Answer (score 1):

First, select both the points/node using the **Node Tool**, (shortcut is **A**). Then click on the **Convert to Sharp** option from the context toolbar. See the below image for reference.

Hope this works out for you.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You could use Command + J, or look at this video for your answer.
http://youtube.com/watch?v=X6CY5W9DS5Q

Gr,
Mart

Comment: **Affinity Designer** not Adobe Illustrator.